# Adding a MaxWidth/MaxHeight to JQuery Supersized

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have a client who suddenly want to restrain the size of the JQuery script Supersized. What he'd like to happen is that the image only expands between 960px and 1020px. If you scale the monitor below that, all other CSS elements would stay in place. I know, I know, defeats the purpose of the plugin, but the client does want the scaling between a min and max.

I've looked at the script and I could probably figure it out with a couple days of poking around, but I figured someone on this great board could sort it out quickly.

So any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

just edit the supersized-css file like this and you got it:

```
#supersized { ... position:absolute; ... }

#supersized img { ...position:relative; .... max-width:1020px; max-height:XXXpx; ...}

#supersized li { ... position:absolute; ...}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use prettyPhoto light box it has a lots of parameters in JS to achieve desired output. http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/

Hope this help!